# What word decribes the way to make the "I18N" abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviations

If I abbreviate a word taking the first letter, then the number of letters in between, and then the last letter, what do you call this action?

For example:

> Internationalization → I18N

Comment: A10N, I would say.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Making up names for things is explicitly off-topic here (see the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq)); but since you apparently made up this action yourself you can name it anything you want. I'm partial to 'Dorothy'.

Comment: @StoneyB this is not made up by the OP. I18N and L10n are extremely common abbreviations in my profession. They are even expressly mentioned in umpteen Wikipedia articles. Coincidentally, that makes this general reference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym

Comment: Wikiedia says they're called [numeronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym), for one type of which *letters between the first and last are replaced with a number representing the number of letters omitted, such as "i18n" for "internationalization".*

Comment: @RegDwighт Who'd a thunk it?! Thanks, that's fascinating. I'll leave my comment in place as a warning against hybris.

Comment: While not disputing that the question might be answered by a single appropriate reference, I note that the Wikipedia article does not do so. "Numeronym" is a noun. The OP sought a word for the action of making a numeronym, which would be a verb.

Comment: There's actually a name for this? I've never seen an example other than "I18n". Note the Wikipedia article cited by RedDwight includes any abbreviation that includes digits under this heading, mixing together some quite different things, from "K9" (where the number is coincidentally pronounced the same as the syllable it replaces) to "911", which is not an "abbreviation" in any normal sense of the word but rather the actual digits dialed to reach emergency services in most of the U.S. Their list of examples then includes some really odd ones, like "WWII" for World War II, where "II" is ...

Comment: ... apparently an abbreviation for ... "II"?

Comment: In this question [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/short-alternatives-of-the-word-authentication-and-the-word-authorisation) there are other examples.

Comment: I think this question would have fared better had the O.P. managed to give some additional examples, or somehow communicated that this practice was not as uncommon as the uninitiated might surmise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Abbreviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation)***. (Or, you might say, ***A10N***.)

*Numeronyms* are those words which are sometimes spelled using numerals. Originally a term for telephone numbers having an alphanumeric meaning. Examples:

- *800-DIGITAL* (344-4825) – once the toll-free number for the legendary computer company
- *i18n*, pronounced *internationalization* – abbreviation using numerals to represent the number of omitted letters
- *K9*, pronounced *canine* – abbreviation using numerals to represent the sound of omitted letters
- *l33t*, pronounced *leet* (slang for *elite*) – using numerals which resemble letters they replace
- *07734*, pronounced *hello* – using numerals which (upside down) resemble letters they replace
- *G8* and *Y2K*, pronounced *gee-eight* and *wye-two-kay* – words originally coined using numerals

Comment: I was looking for the word 'Numeronym' or something similar... but I like your answer, so I accept it.