# Does "numeric" abbreviation eg i18n have a name?

Tags: abbreviations, terminology

In the computer programming context, several long words are commonly abbreviated using the formula `first letter, number of letters between, last letter`.

Eg `internationalization` --> `i18n`

Is there a name for this technique of abbreviation?

Is there a name for the abbreviation so created?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91004

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [i18nguy.com](http://www.i18nguy.com/origini18n.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym), i18n is an example of a *numeronym*.

That is a word that uses numbers in it.

Other examples include K9 (dog), 411 (information), 101 (basic introduction to a subject).